# Let T be a tree, then the Ramsey number $R(T, K_n)=(|T|-1)(n-1)+1$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading the proof of this proposition:
[image]

In the last paragraph, how is the underlined part related with the assumption? If it is by contradiction, shouldn't we have $\deg(v)<|T|-1$? Or $k-1< |T|$ for some reason?

Below are my thoughts:

In the second case, we first show that coloring $c$ using $|T|$ colors at least, so $|T|\leq \chi_C(G)=k$? (I assume last two paragraphs serve for the second case.) But how do we get $k-1< |T|$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's also not clear what the notation $\chi_C(G)$ is supposed to mean, and $k$ gets used in paragraph 2 long before it gets defined. Just read a better version of this proof: Proposition 9.2.1 in Diestel, or Theorem 8.3.14 in West, or [the original paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190010118) if you have access.